# Dynamically show fields of the generic type through intellisense

Tags: java

In Servoy, a development and deployment platform, you have the possibility to use what is called a JSFoundSet which is an object containing record objects defined by its SQL. Such a JSFoundSet is created as follows using the appropriate annotation:

```
/** @type{JSFoundSet<db:/database/table_name}*/
var fs = null;
```

from this point on you can use in your code the variable `fs` to get or set values to the properties of `table_name`. So if I would create a foundset of table **Customer** and this table contains the columns **id**, **firstName** and **lastName**, then the Servoy platform provides intellisense that allows me to do this:

```
fs.id = 1;
fs.firstName = 'John';
fs.lastName = 'Doe';
```

Since I use a lot of Java too, I wanted to see if I can create something similar of this in Java. So I want to create a class `FoundSet` of a certain generic type, say of type *Customer* in our example, after which in my code I can create an object of this class and then access the public fields (set/get) of FoundSet. While typing I wish to see these fields show up through intellisense.

Is there a library or some sort that allows me to define some annotations as the Servoy example to accomplish this?

Comment: It seems you are looking for an ORM in Java. That generates the code to get/set values and persist in a DB.

Comment: Yes, but I wish to experiment between both Java and Servoy to create some sort of a hybrid of both. I really like the simplicity of creating an object of a certain type as the JSFoundSet example and then have the IDE intellisense suggest the correct fields that belong to the type and all of this in Java.

Comment: Java is statically typed with metaprogramming capabilities limited to annotation processing, so you cannot do that kind of thing without further compilation step. Most ORM frameworks have IDE support. (Groovy and Scala might be a better option if you prefer the syntax you described.)